# Why is it bad practice to submit pull request from master branch?

Tags: git, github

It is said to be bad practice to submit pull requests from master branch. I am trying to understand the implications of doing so but can’t find an comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Please only one question per question :) And I'm afraid the first question/paragraph is mainly opinion-based

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @knittl. Do you know where I could learn about the first question?

Comment: whether it is or isn't is an opinion and hence off topic for stack overflow

Comment: @gman Understood. Deleting the question. That being said, do you know where I can find help on topics such as this one? Love Stack Overflow but understand these kind of questions may not belong here.

Comment: @gman I totally agree with you but it makes me wonder which forum on SO network is more suitable for such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://blog.jasonmeridth.com/posts/do-not-issue-pull-requests-from-your-master-branch/) is the problem statement if you submit a PR from master:

> You do not want to issue pull requests from your fork’s master branch
>   on Github.com to the parent repisitory because any new changes you add
>   to the master branch will automatically show up in the pull request.
>   That means changes you did not intend to be there, would now be there.

The post goes into more details. It talks about `github` but can be applied to all git repositories